# Y-Axis of plot in python skewed

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am new to Python and I've been trying to create a program that plots a lorenz curve. When I don't define the function it works fine but when I do, the numbers still work out but the plot looks wonky. I can't figure out how to fix the y-axis- My range is 0-100, and I'd like intervals of 10 or 20 but the program smushes all the y-axis values together. I've tried everything I've found on the internet so far but nothing worked. Here's my code:

```
def lorenz():
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import numpy as np

    print("Enter distribution per quintile from poorest to richest one by one. Entering the starting 0 value is not necessary. Make sure they add up to 100%")
    T1=input("Distribution for bottom 20%: ")
    T2=input("Distribution for next 20%: ")
    T3=input("Distribution for next 20%: ")
    T4=input("Distribution for next 20%: ")
    T5=input("Distribution for top 20%: ")

    Q1=T1
    Q2=Q1+T2
    Q3=Q2+T3
    Q4=Q3+T4
    Q5=100

    x1=(0,20,40,60,80,100)
    y1=(0,Q1,Q2,Q3,Q4,Q5)
    x2=(0,100)
    y2=(0,100)
    x3=(0,100)
    y3=(0,0)

    plt.plot(x1, y1,'-o', label="Country X")
    plt.plot(x2, y2, 'g' ,label="Perfect Equality")
    plt.plot(x3, y3, 'r',label="Perfect Inequality")
    plt.ylim(0,100)


    plt.title('Lorenz Curve of Country X')
    plt.xlabel('% of Population')
    plt.ylabel('% of Income')
    plt.legend()
    plt.legend(loc='upper left')
    plt.show()
```

Here's how it ends up looking

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The reason your plots are skewed is because inputs are being read as strings and not integers. Convert them to integers and it will work. Below are my adjustments:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as pat
import numpy as np

def lorenz():
  print("Enter distribution per quintile from poorest to richest one by one. Entering the starting 0 value is not necessary. Make sure they add up to 100%")
  T1=input("Distribution for bottom 20%: ")
  T2=input("Distribution for next 20%: ")
  T3=input("Distribution for next 20%: ")
  T4=input("Distribution for next 20%: ")
  T5=input("Distribution for top 20%: ")

  Q1=int(T1)
  Q2=int(Q1)+int(T2)
  Q3=int(Q2)+int(T3)
  Q4=int(Q3)+int(T4)
  Q5=100

  x1=(0,20,40,60,80,100)
  y1=(0,Q1,Q2,Q3,Q4,Q5)
  x2=np.linspace(0,100, num=6)
  y2=np.linspace(0,100, num=6)
  x3=np.linspace(0,100, num=6)
  y3=np.zeros((6, 1))

  lorenz_fig = plt.figure(figsize=[10,3])
  lorenz_ax = lorenz_fig.add_axes([0, 0, 1, 1], label=['Country X', 
                                                        'Perfect Equality',
                                                        'Perfect Inequality'])
  lorenz_ax.plot(x1, y1,'-o', x2, y2, 'g', x3, y3, 'r')

  plt.title('Lorenz Curve of Country X')
  plt.xlabel('% of Population')
  plt.ylabel('% of Income')
  lorenz_fig.legend(lorenz_ax.lines, ['Country X', 'Perfect Equality',
                               'Perfect Inequality'], 
                               fontsize='large', loc='upper left')

  plt.show()
```